# LP gas logs main burner issue

Tags: gas, fireplace

The pilot is lit but when the main burner ignites it immediately goes out. It had been working fine all season and just developed this issue. Is there a thermocouple or thermopile sensor to keep the flow of gas going to the main burner?

Comment: You'll have to post the model number for anyone to be able to help.   Most models with constant pilot are older and main burner flame sensors tend to be newer.  From this point of view, we have no idea what you have.

Comment: The usual thermocouple type control is actually called a powerpile or pilot generator. One type looks like a pencil and the other is in the shape of a wafer. Both have wires coming from the bottom